# 404 error Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm beginner in Django programing, and I want to show a view on my browser.
My code is:

polls/view.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")

def animal(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello cat")
```

polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^animal$', views.animal, name='animal'),
)
```

When I show index view, everything in okay. But, when I show animal view, my browser not found the page, and I dont know why.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Your second URL pattern isn't terminated. It needs to be:

```
url(r'^animal/$', views.animal, name='animal')
```

also, you want to list your URLs from most specific to least specific. Also note that you can use the patterns prefix to keep your code a bit more DRY.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    url(r'^animal/$', 'animal', name='animal'),
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
)
```

as Django will try to match them top-down

Comment: Removing the `$` entirely sounds like a better idea to me.

Comment: and why is that? `$` is simply the end of the RegEx. Unless specifically overridden, Django URL patterns end with `/`, therefore `/animal` and `/animal/` are not the same pattern.

Comment: I always thought ending a RegEx with `$` means only match if the string ends there. I'll admit I don't know the details of what parts of the URL Django tries to match against the pattern.

Comment: That's true, except in this case, the URL doesn't end with `l` it ends with `/` unless the OP has overridden `APPEND_SLASH` in settings.py: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#append-slash to be `False`

Comment: For a quick test, head over to https://www.regex101.com/#python. Use the OP's original regex: `^animal$` and then enter the url Django will try to match: `animal/` for the test string and you'll get a "no match" response.

Comment: So, by removing `$` in the regex, then everything under `animal/` will be handled by the animal function, which is probably how it should be. If it was a specific page, like `animal.html`, then the regex should end in `$`. At least, this is the way I would consider things to be most tidy.

Comment: Unless I'm building up patterns via `include` directives, I always terminate the pattern(s) with `$`

Comment: Note that `urlpatterns` and passing views as strings are [deprecated in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns).

Comment: Yeah! Less code is always a good thing. I haven't had a chance to read much of the 1.8 docs yet.